# Можно с помощью php вызвать allert?

Tags: php

Можно с помощью php вызвать allert?

Comment: a**l**lert точно нельзя ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если Алерт в js то можно вот так вот :

```
<?
echo "<script>alert('text')</script>";
?>
```

Comment: echo "<script>alert('text');</script>";
точка с запятой должна алерт закрывать

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя, ибо php исполняется на стороне сервера. То что вы видите в браузере - это хтмл код, сгенерированный в результате запроса. Алерт можно вызвать только яваскриптом.
з.ы. ну конечно можно установить сервер на локалхост (ваш компьютер) и через php вызвать функцию WinApi MessageBox, но это извращение и к теме не имеет отношения :)